# How do Views relate/loosely couple to Annotations? Annotationsarray I got, Views I need

Tags: swift, macos, mapkit, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

**SryImNew**: 
(lets say I want to Display gliphXYZ if title == "home")

"Annotation views are loosely coupled to a corresponding annotation object" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview

How to couple them loosely, and where?
Or do I already have multiple MKAnnotationView automatically, if so how to address them & their properties?

***My Case***

I have running: An app that shows multiple pins for locations on a map 
by

```
rawArrayWithFormat=[[namestring,lat,long][namestring,lat...]]

class Place: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
      var title: String?
      var subtitle: String?
      var latitude: Double
      var longitude:Double

      var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
      return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
      }

      init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
      self.latitude = latitude
      self.longitude = longitude
}
```

**Function that returns Array of [Place] by iterating through rawArray**

```
func getMapAnnotations() -> [Place] {
var annotations:Array = [Place]()    

for item in rawArray {

    let lat = (item[1] as AnyObject) as! Double
    let long = (item[2] as AnyObject) as! Double
    let annotation = Place(latitude: lat, longitude: long)


    annotation.title = (item[0] as AnyObject) as? String
    annotations.append(annotation)
} 
return annotations
```

And then in **ViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
...
```

finally **I call in override** func viewDidLoad{

```
         mapView.addAnnotations(getMapAnnotations())
```

Comment: MKAnnotationView is a subclass of NSView, which suggests that you can use the identifier property.

Comment: I've read this before and tried a lot. I had set an Identifier "let identifier:Boolean [...]" in my getMapAnnotations() so the PlaceObjects had them. Could you please be more specific from that point on? I am a newbie, have tried the most absurd things with all the stuff autocomplete "View/MK" suggested at many places but failed.